# can someone clarify issues with root relative URL and htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am rewriting some of my URLs using the htaccess engine but I am running into this issue that I really don't understand.

Using the following rule in htaccess

`RewriteRule ^category/(\d+)$  category.php?category=$1 [NC,L]`

I set the relative path in HTML to `<a href='category/{$cat_id}'>{$catTitle}</a>` this works fine if I am going to this link from another page. Although if I open the link from the same page the resulting URL becomes `http://localhost/CMS/category/category/1` which is not valid. Someone proposed that I should use what is called "root-relative URL" which requires changing the path to `<a href='/CMS/category/{$cat_id}'>` that solved the problem. What I am trying to understand why `<a href='category.php?category={$cat_id}'>`worked without using the root-relative URL and adding the `/cms/` before using htaccsses does that mean I have to change each URL I have in my code and add root-relative URL? Is this how htaccess engine works with paths?

Thank you.

Comment: Your links are relative to the current location. So if you're at /cat/meow.html and you follow a link to "dog/woof.html” your browser will take you to /cat/dog/woof.html. Your links should all be absolute (full URL) or relative to the root (start with slash) so that "/dog/woof.html” always takes you to [webroot]dog/woof.html

Comment: I see; is there a way maybe using regex in the htaccess to add the /CMS/ so that i don't have to go back an change my paths.

Comment: `<base>` tag or` /` end of your full url and change `[NC,L]` to `[L,NC]` dont think there is another way.

Comment: This might work for your base url RewriteRule ^/

Comment: base tag worked well thank you sir